How change value of constant inside SystemVerilog package based on top level parameter of testbench?
I have created a model of a design in SystemVerilog. It uses fixed point maths. Some top level parameters of the module are used to specify what scaling factor to use for the calculation within the module. This affects the values of predefined constants and also how the scale down operation and rounding is performed.
Right now I have multiple predefined constants and then choose one of them based on the parameter value using if..else.. block. There are multiple different functions that are almost identical except what constants they use during calculation and how the result is scaled down.
My question is, is it possible to pass the top level testbench module parameter into the package and use that to choose what value the constants should have i.e parameterize the package using testbench top level module parameter?
I am from VHDL background and the `if vs #if confuses me. Also, I am not sure if what I am trying to do is possible in SystemVerilog using testbench module top level parameters.

Your question is very close to an XY problem. SystemVerilog packages cannot be parameterized, nor can you select a different package to import based on a parameter. There are many possible approaches if we had more specific details about what you ultimately need to accomplish.
If you are going to have different top-level testbenches, you can have each testbench import different packages and the different parameter values down to your design.
You can compile different versions of your package into different libraries, and chose the library you want at the same time you choose the testbench you want. Compilation scripts will be a tools specific issue, not part of the SystemVerilog language.
You can put functions in your package that select return values based on the top-level testbench parameters.

VHDL has parameters that can be passed to pacakge so I assumed that it should be possible with SV as well. However, it seems that it is not.

Assuming you're using a UVM testbench, your test lives outside of a package, and can access the testbench hierarchy, as well as the parameters of instantiated modules. Simply extract them and assign to a config class object in your package. I personally put them in an associative array keyed off the param name.
That said, if these are the parameters of a top-level DUT, then they should already be under your DV control. If you instead maintain defines, those can be used to assign to your TB instances and uvm classes, rather than have to extract from hierarchy. Also, if your parameter list changes, your edits will now be centralized in one file.
